# Circular arrows with gradient

Tags: css, css-shapes

I tried to make it with border but gradient makes it impossible. Maybe I can make four divs and make it like that?

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Tried to make two backgrounds with padding so the second background will be like a border, but gradient doesn't work like that :)

Comment: I thought maybe I can make 4 incline divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS might not be the best way to create such shapes. You should use SVG instead.

We can use SVG's `path` element to create a pointing arrow like shape and fill it with gradient created with `linearGradient`.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) is a detailed information about SVG paths:

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background: #333;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#212121"></stop>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#a7a7a7"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <path id="arrow" x="0" y="0" d="M0,200
                                    A200,200 0, 0, 1, 200,0
                                    L225,25
                                    L200,50
                                    A150,150, 0, 0, 0 50,200
                                    L25,175" fill="url(#gradient)" />
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(0,400) rotate(270)"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(400,400) rotate(180)"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#arrow" transform="translate(400,0) rotate(90)"></use>
  <use xlink:href="#arrow"></use>

</svg>
```